# Should unchangeable usernames be the Primary Key of MySQL table?

Tags: mysql

I'm creating the backend for a SaaS and was curious as to whether my license keys should be used as the Primary Key or the usernames. The usernames will never be changed. To me, it makes sense to have the usernames be the primary key to yield the fastest query lookup for a login request. Thanks.

Comment: It shouldn't be the primary key, but you can place an index, including a unique index, on your username column.

Comment: VARCHAR as primary key may be expensive when joining and/or foreign key by this column needed. And the size of any other index increases.

Comment: Ah! Good point, didn't think about that. Thanks!